# Looking for a particular data in JSON hashmap

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I need to look for AccountNo field value in different json payloads. AccountNo can exist at any level in json payload. I need to check if AccountNo exists and then print value in logger.

I am using below enricher but I want to iterate through the Hashmap in mule to check if AccountNo key exists anywhere and then get the value.

Also please suggest if any other way to parse json itself. 
In xpath "//AccountNo" will look for AccountNo in whole xml document. I am after something similar.

`<enricher target="#[flowVars.myJsonMap]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
   <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
</enricher>
<logger message="#[flowVars.myJsonMap.employees[0].AccountNo]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>    </flow>`

Please find below example json payloads

```
{
"Account": {
"AccountName": "John",
"AccountNo": "4234324"
 }
 }

{
"Order": {
"OrderId": "34234242",
"ServiceOrder": [
  {
    "AccountNo": "231232",
    "ServiceOrderId": "54654698787"
  },
  {
    "AccountNo": "231232",
    "ServiceOrderId": "78979879797"
  }
  ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its a hashmap

you can use `yourmap.get(keyvalue)` to get value.

```
<logger message="#[flowVars.myJsonMap.yourkey?]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: In this case I do not know where my key will be nested. Please find example payload above in my original comment.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume the following:

- Your payload contains nested Maps and Lists along with other Objects
- AccountNo may exists at any level of your payload

You can use a Groovy transformer to recursively parse your payload and collect all existing AccountNo in a List:

```
//recursively parse any Map or List in myObject
//and store AccountNo objects accountNoList
def parseObject(myObject, accountNoList) {
  if (myObject instanceof java.util.Map) {
    //if Map, check for AccountNo field
    if(myObject.AccountNo != null){
        accountNoList.add(myObject.AccountNo)
    }

    //seek for more AccountNo in Map
    for(e in myObject) {
      parseObject(e.value, accountNoList)
    }
  } else if (myObject instanceof java.lang.Iterable) {
    //if Iterable, parse each values
    for (value in myObject) {
       parseObject(value, accountNoList)
    }
  }
}

myJsonPayload = message.getInvocationProperty('myJsonPayload')
myAccountNoList = [] //init an empty list which will be filled
parseObject(myJsonPayload, myAccountNoList)
return myAccountNoList
```

Then simply use a Logger.

Comment: Can I use java to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not dealing with large set of json data, just convert the json to XMl using JSONToXMLTransformer and then, use XPATH to look for the data anywhere in the document. This way, you could avoid writing any additional code to parse the json file.

Comment: With nested json tags json to xml transformer I have found doesn't return complete payload.

Comment: Can you please provide your json payload where "account" tags are repeated?? I have done something in the past to parse the json recursively using dataweave. I will check if the same code works for your payload.

Comment: I have added example payloads in original comment above. Thanks.